# jQuery changing src of video player. What to do if video not found

Tags: php, jquery

I am changing the src of a video player using jquery and loading the new src.  I am hard coding the src from s3.

Sometimes the video may not be there.  I want to alert the user if the video is not found.

Here is my jQuery:

```
        var ez = $('#EZ');
        var ezSource = "http://videos.s3.amazonaws.com/videoTest.mp4";
        ez.on('click', function(){
            $('#mp4').attr('src', ezSource);
            $('#videoClip').load();
        });
```

I don't really know how to check if video is not found.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Showing_fallback_content_when_no_source_could_be_decoded

Answer (score 0):

Handle the error event

```
$('#mp4').on('error', function() {
   alert("Unable to load the video");
});
```

Fildde [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0mx3d22r/)

Comment: Thank you very much!!  That is what I needed.  You are awesome!

Comment: @user16454 An upvote and accept answer is appreciated :)